# .htaccess still showing .html extension

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am using cpanel.
In the public_html folder I have 2 files:
home.html
test.html

home.html links to test.html with:

```
<a href="https://example.com/test.html">Test</a>
```

I do not want to display the .html extension in the browser.
My htaccess file is as follows, but the .html extension is still displayed:

```
# BEGIN GD-SSL
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^(.+)$
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ^education\.mekan\-turk\.com$
RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
Header add Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=300"
</IfModule>
# END GD-SSL


# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

Comment: mod_rewrite does not change your HTML code for you, you need to change the URLs contained in there yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following, based on your shown samples. Trying to fix OP's attempts here. I am assuming that OP wants to hit URL like `http://localhost:80/test` which should be served by `http://localhost:80/test.html` here.

Fix is, when you are checking condition  `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f` then while Rewriting rule you need NOT to mention `.html` else it will show it in browser. Also keeping your last 2 rules at top will help here.

```
# BEGIN GD-SSL
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/%{REQUEST_URI} [L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^(.+)$
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ^education\.mekan\-turk\.com$
RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
Header add Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=300"
</IfModule>
# END GD-SSL


# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Fair warning I haven't tested it yet should work I believe.

Comment: I think you have code `# BEGIN WordPress` twice here

Comment: @anubhava, Thank you sir, I copy/pasted from OP's question :) fixed it now, thank you.

Comment: Do I now need to remove .html from the url links in the html files e.g. <a href="https://example.com/test">Test</a>. ?

Comment: @AbsZaa, I am sorry, I didn't get it, could you please explain it more.

Comment: I replaced the htaccess with your code.

home.html contains a link to test.html
<a href="https://example.com/test.html">Test</a></p>

If I click the link, the search bar displays:
https://example.com/test.html

I want it to display:
https://example.com/test

Do I need to delete .html extension from the href url:
<a href="https://example.com/test">Test</a></p>

Comment: do I need to add: Options +MultiViews

Comment: I am using the suggested code but, the browser is still showing .html. I have deleted cache and cookies and tried safari and chrome.